# Understanding why we use methods on strings in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've just started learning Python and I've got to a point where I'm a little confused on why we use `.upper()` in, for example, `print("Hello, World!".upper())`. I've read through some answers provided on similar *stackoverflow* questions, any they all the general theme, "you use the notation `.upper()` for methods".

From my understanding, methods are just special cases of functions that belong to classes. If this is the case, why do we use things like `.upper()`, `.title()`, `.isalhpa()` etc. on simple strings like `"Hello, World!"` when they don't belong to a class?

Comment: String is a class. Strings can have methods just like any other class.

Comment: Its like Java, where strings are classes. You should try reading the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html)

Comment: You can also have [methods on integer and float literals](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#additional-methods-on-float). e.g `5.0.is_integer()` returns `True`

Comment: In python every name refers to an object and every object has a type defined by a class.

Comment: So, `"Hello, World!"` would just be an instance of the class, `String`?

Comment: @Enroy Yes. The string creation syntax using quotes is just "sugar" that the language provides to make string creation easy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good thing to get comfortable with is checking types and methods of different objects. E.g.

```
>>> stringy = 'Hello world!'
>>> type(stringy)
str
```

Then to get information on string-type objects:

```
>>> help(str)
class str(object)
# <A description of the class will be here>

Methods defined here:
# <various methods>
upper(...)
    S.upper() -> str

    Return a copy of S converted to uppercase.
```

So what we were actually doing in our first line is creating an object of the str() class:

```
stringy = str('Hello world!')
```

Hope that makes sense :-)

Answer (score 2):

As other people have pointed out this happens because in python strings, as all of the other types I am aware of, are objects. Strings specifically are objects of the `str` class. You may look [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#textseq) for more on this.

Also methods usually refer to functions bound to objects. This excellent  [post](https://julien.danjou.info/blog/2013/guide-python-static-class-abstract-methods) about how methods work on python may interest you.